# Emacs: select quoted string as one operation

Tags: emacs, elisp

In programming we ofter have a task of selecting text between quotes. Suppose, we have the following PHP code:

```
lwt_shared_save_conditions_to_session($conditions, "bundles_listing"■);
```

The cursor position is shown with black square. And we want to select and copy the text "bundles_listing" into the clipboard. I created the following function:

```
(defun select-quoted-text ()
  (interactive)
  (search-backward "\"")
  (forward-char 1)
  (cua-set-mark)
  (backward-char 1)
  (search-backward "\"")
  (kill-ring-save (region-beginning) (region-end))
  )
```

It will select the text between quotes.

How can I do the following:

1.Fold this code into 1 function call:

```
(forward-char 1)
(cua-set-mark)
(backward-char 1)
```

2. Select text both between single `'` and double `"` quotes.

Comment: you can do it by double click on a quote character.

Comment: @sds Yes, clicking works. But moving mouse is slow, so I'd prefer a function, that could be called by a quick keyboard shortcut.

Comment: Use the excellent expand-region.el ? https://github.com/magnars/expand-region.el With successive calls you select successive sexps. It works with single and double quotes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
(defun copy-quoted ()
  "Copy current string into kill-ring.
The point can be anywhere in the string."
  (interactive)
  (let ((beg (or (nth 8 (syntax-ppss))
                 (and (memq (char-after (point))
                            '(?\" ?\'))
                      (point))))
        end)
    (when beg
      (setq end
            (save-excursion
              (goto-char beg)
              (forward-sexp)
              (point)))
      (kill-ring-save beg end))))
```

Answer (score 1):

Here's how I'd do it interactively (rather than defining a function for it):

```
C-SPC C-M-b M-w
```

That runs the following commands:

```
set-mark-command
backward-sexp
kill-ring-save
```